# docker isn't able to add local files to container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, ubuntu-20.04

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

- ./7.3/web/Dockerfile
- ./etc/php/*

So I'm in the `.` directory and do `sudo docker build -t test 7.3/web` and it builds the container but stops at `ADD etc/php /usr/local/etc/php`, giving me the following error:

```
ADD failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat etc/php: file does not exist
```

The file (well directory), however, does exist. When I do `ls -latr ./etc/php` I see this:

```
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 neubert neubert 4096 Jan  3 23:32 conf.d
drwxr-xr-x 4 neubert neubert 4096 Jan  3 23:32 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 neubert neubert 4096 Jan  3 23:32 .
```

So relative to the directory I'm running the command in `etc/php` exists. Relative to the directory the that the Dockerfile exists in `etc/php` doesn't exist (it's `../../etc/php`).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your cake and eat it by using the `-f` flag like so:

`docker build -t test -f ./7.3/web/Dockerfile .`

The above runs the specified Dockerfile, but uses the current directory as the context path (which is used as the base for ADDing and COPYing in files).

More details here among the very handy docs of the Docker website: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#specify-a-dockerfile--f

Answer (score 2):

> So I'm in the . directory and do sudo docker build -t test 7/3/web and it builds the container but stops at ADD etc/php /usr/local/etc/php...

The argument you provide to `docker build` (`7/3/web`) defines the "build context". Docker can only access files located in or below this directory.

The easiest solution is probably to move your `Dockerfile` into the toplevel directory and adjust your paths to be relative from there.

You don't *have* to move the Dockerfile (as Jason points out, you can reference it anywhere via `-f`), but that makes the organization of the directory more obvious.